# Dynamically add input via jQuery, however all jQuery inputs do not receive focus styling?

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding inputs to a form when a user clicks on an anchor tag that has the jQuery click event attached to it.

```
$(".add-input").click(function () {

  $("div.form-item").append(get_input());

});
```

The above function successfully adds new inputs to the form, however I have another jQuery function that adds styling to the currently focused input like so:

```
$("input, textarea").focus(function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass("cur-focus");
});
```

This function works great for inputs that were apart of the original form, however all the dynamically added inputs do not have the class added by the above event handler.

Both of these event handlers are inside of the $(document).ready function.

Is there a way for the dynamically added inputs to also be bound to my focus event handler on inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `on` or `delegate`.

Using `on` jQuery 1.7+

```
$("form").on("focus", "input, textarea",function () {
     $(this).parent().addClass("cur-focus");
});
```

Using `delegate` for older versions

```
$("form").delegate("input, textarea", "focus", function () {
     $(this).parent().addClass("cur-focus");
});
```

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.7+ and this solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functionality. Both of these automatically attach matching elements when they're created.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` version:

```
$("body").on('focus','input, textarea', function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass("cur-focus");
});
```

For better performance instead of `body` you should give the closest element that contains all the `input` and `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an event handler.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/